# Inserting special characters in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cql

Hi I am trying to insert the following text into cassandra using cql (cqlsh 3.0.2 | Cassandra 1.2.5)

```
INSERT INTO "MediaCategory" ("MCategoryID", "SubMCategoryName", "PhotoRankID", 
  "VirtualTourID", "LangID") VALUES (14,'Vue depuis l'hôtel',92002,192002, 1036);
```

But when i try doing that i get an error saying Invalid syntax .Basically I am unable to unsert anything which has "l'"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use double `'` (i.e., `''`) to represent an `'` in CQL.  For example:

```
insert into text_table (text_data) values ('Vue depuis l''hôtel');
```